# Detect user interaction without delegates

Tags: objective-c, swift, uiview, uiscrollview, uitextfield

Is it possible to detect user interaction (like swiping a scrollview or start editing a textfield) without using delegates or notifications? Just using the most basic touch events possible.

I've been trying to use touchesBegan and touchesEnded but these are not always called.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can just connect an IBAction to your UITextField Sent Events - Editing Changed, so every time the text field changes your IBAction will be called. You can do the same for Editing Did Begin and Editing Did End.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29045440/2303865

Comment: I want to use the original UIView capabilities

Comment: I have no idea what is your issue and or what you are trying to achieve. That method doesn't  need delegates and or notification. So why it isn't enough for you to do what you want? What do you mean original capabilities?

Comment: @godmoney are you trying to hijack input or something?

Answer (score 0):

You can identify the touched object and perform actions you required.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{

    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    if ([touch.view isKindOfClass: UITextField.class])
    {
      if (![(UITextField *)touch.view isFirstResponder])
      {
        //start editing
        [(UITextField *)touch.view becomeFirstResponder];
      }
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Similarly in "touchesEnded" will do.

Comment: touchesBegan will only called in ViewController Class.