# EditingChanged Textfield function not working

Tags: ios, swift

hello If I implement below  function in my controller then `EditingChanged` function doesn't work

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        textField.text = (textField.text! as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string.uppercaseString)

        return false
    }
```

This is the `EditingChanged` Function

```
    firstNameTxtField.addTarget(self, action: "textFieldDidChange:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingChanged)

 func textFieldDidChange(textField: UITextField) {

       print("hello")
    }
```

Comment: Ok no. You need to set your textfield delegate to your class. Then you can access the delegate methods of your textfield. I will post an answer on it

Comment: @hellosheikh http://stackoverflow.com/a/29045440/2303865

Comment: @Devster101 Sir The functions work properly but the problem is they are not working both at the same time

Comment: @hellosheikh Why would you need both of them? You can do whatever you need inside your textField EditingChanged method. Your problem looks like is the poor naming parameter of your method. Just change it from `textField` to `sender`. `func textFieldDidChange(sender: UITextField) {`

Comment: @LeoDabus well first function I need because I want to show all characters capitalize and the other is I want to get the user info when he types

Comment: @LeoDabus I changed it into sender but still didn't work

Comment: all you need is to make your text become capitalized string ? https://www.dropbox.com/s/uqn9sqd827slpac/valueChanged.zip?dl=1

Comment: @LeoDabus Let me check

Comment: @LeoDabus your code is throwing an errror

'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<valueChanged.ViewController 0x15f63c830> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key myTextField.'

Comment: @hellosheikh not my code. I tested it here and it works fine. download the project again and test it

Comment: okay it works somehow thank you very much. But still some slight problem. I have around 6 textboxes. I want to keep them in one function. I am talking about this function 

 @IBAction func editingChanged(sender: UITextField) {} I wanted all the textbox values in one function. I don't want to do for all the textbox individually. so to acheive this functionality I drop the drag pointer of 2nd text box in this same function and it didn't work. meaning the letters are small showing

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34941447/edit

Answer (score 0):

I face the same problem too. I am able to solve it by using an IBAction to bind instead of UIControlEvents as you described above. Because sometimes, the later fails to respond which is weird.

```
@IBAction func myTextFieldEditingBegins(_ sender: Any) {
    //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to set delegate for your text field. Set the delegate as

```
yourtextField.delegate = self
```

Now, EditingChanged will work as expected.